# Crystal Reports Charts with detail data and hyperlinks

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm using Crystal Reports 2008 and I'm not sure if what the end users want can even be accomplished.  And, if it can be accomplished, I'm not sure how to do it.

I have created a report that brings back a list of patients and their doctors.  The detail gives patient information.  If a patient is complying with doctors' orders, then they are in compliance and if they are not, they're out of compliance. I'm being asked to provide a chart where at a quick glance, a doctor can see how many patients are in compliance and how many patients are out.  Then, he wants to be able to click on the chart and be brought down to the detail and be able to see a list of those patients that are out of compliance.

I've managed to create the chart in the report header, but since I want this report to run for all doctors at once and not one at a time, I'm not sure how to make the chart for only one doctoring.  I tried adding a group for the doctor, but that isn't working.  It is still putting them all together.  Next, I can't even find a way to add a hyperlink for them to be able to drill down.  I'm sure I've set this up incorrectly, so perhaps I need to start all over.

Any ideas would be fantastic, as I'm truly at a loss on how to set this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to report one doctor at a time, add a selection formula on the doctor's name or ID.

If you want to report all doctors, with a separate graph for each doctor, then add a group for the doctor and move the chart into the group header.

To be able to list all the patients on drilldown, add the relevant fields to the detail section, then **hide** (don't suppress) the detail section. The user should be able to drill down to the detail section by double-clicking almost anywhere in the Group Header (*except* the graph, at least in CR10).

If you only want the patients that are out of compliance to be visible in drilldown, then conditionally suppress the detail section where the patients are in compliance.

Comment: thanks so much!  I was having so much trouble trying to create the chart.  I didn't realize that I could put it in the group header!  Thanks again, as this is working perfectly!